# compiling multiple files in netfilter

Tags: linux, kernel, netfilter

How can I compile multiple files (files calling functions in other files) in kernel module?

Answer (score 1):

I'm interpreting your question to mean, you want to link multiple compilation units together into one module?

There's plenty of examples of this in the kernel source code itself; the general gist of it is to write `Makefile` like

```
obj-$(CONFIG_FOO) += foo.o
foo-objs: bar.o
```

This will link `foo.o` and `bar.o` together for `foo.ko` if `CONFIG_FOO=m`.  See [The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide # Modules Spanning Multiple Files](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x351.html) for a more detailed explanation.